# How to create grid in Meteor that looks like the homepage of atmospherejs?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a grid system (the trending part) that looks like atmosphere homepage.
https://atmospherejs.com/

I have an each loop that looks like below. I want to wrap each "text" into its own box and display all in a grid system.

```
{{#each random_display}}
  {{text}}
{{/each}
```

Comment: here's a link to atmosphere's github page: https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/tree/master/app

Comment: thanks! i found the github page too. I cloned it but realized there were so many errors when i build it (which doesn't have much to do with the grid). I just want to know what's the proper way of creating such grid if anyone has done it before.

Comment: dude, atmosphere has done it before.  If there are errors when you clone the project, check them out.  Figure out what is causing the errors and then fix them.  Or else write the code piece by piece from the ground up

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a link to the github page for atmosphere](https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/tree/master/app).

What I recommend you do, if you want that functionality, is to clone the repository, using `git clone https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere.git`, and then go through some of the client side code, figure out what it does, and literally copy/paste it into your project if it has the functionality you want.